# Analysis .NET Core console app Crash dump from Linux (ARM32, Debian, RaspberryPi3B+) via lldb failed

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, .net-core

I'm using .NET CORE 2.1.1 on a ARM32 Linux Iot board (Raspberry Pi3B+).

I've collected a crash dump for my console app, by following the  [analyzing dump on linux](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2017/02/26/analyzing-a-net-core-core-dump-on-linux/), I'm trying to do a analysis via `lldb`.

the post seems a bit old, the path of `libsosplugin.so` now changed under to `/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.1/`, meanwhile, I can't see anything from command `ldd libsosplugin.so | grep lldb`, and this is my `ldd libsosplugin.so` result:

> linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7edcb000)
>
> /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76ee4000)
>
> libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0x76d87000)
>
> libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x76d08000)
>
> libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x76cdb000)
>
> libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76b9c000)
>
> /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76f10000)

so I have no way to know what it the target `lldb`, then I have to try from `lldb-3.5` to `lldb-4.0` via `apt-get install lldb-x.x` one by one.

I've noticed, 3.5 - 3.9 have the issue to accept my key stroke! all key strokes were interpreted as a Uncode string, finally, `lldb-4.0` can load the dump and plugin:

```
    plugin load /opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.1/libsosplugin.so
    setclrpath /opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.1
```

but once I key in `sos PrintException`, `lldb` crashed it self with Segmentation fault, everything listed below:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/crash_dumps $ lldb-4.0 $(which dotnet) --core ./core.dotnet.1402.raspberrypi.1533274692
(lldb) target create "/usr/local/bin/dotnet" --core "./core.dotnet.1402.raspberrypi.1533274692"
Core file '/home/pi/crash_dumps/./core.dotnet.1402.raspberrypi.1533274692' (arm) was loaded.
(lldb) plugin load /opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.1/libsosplugin.so
(lldb) setclrpath /opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.1
(lldb) sos PrintException
(lldb)
Stack dump:
0.      HandleCommand(command = "")
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `ldd | grep lldb` no longer works because it was considered a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/12098. I think the goal is that you should be able to load it with any lldb version.

Comment: so any suggestion for my problem? what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `libsosplugin.so` shipped with .NET Core SDKs 2.1.30x (.NET Core 2.1) [requires](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/building/debugging-instructions.md) `lldb-3.8` or `lldb-3.9`, so I'd expect `4.0` version to throw all sorts of errors including segfault.

Not sure why you're having unicode issue, though. When I used `lldb-3.9` for .NET Core it did print character codes for certain keys (`up`, `Ctrl+`), but the rest was fine and that was x64, not ARM. Maybe that's the separate issue caused by environment settings that can be googled separately.

Comment: I've tried another ARM32 Linux board (ASUS Tinker Board S), the behavior is a little bit diff but finally failed for analysis dump, also see https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/issues/58    looks like the lldb itself have problem in ARM platform.